# Xcode 4 to Xcode 3.2 Compatability

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app written that compiles and runs fine in Xcode 4.2.  I want to port it into Xcode 3.2 (I have the compatibility option check marked) but Xcode 3.2 gives me an error for some reason.  Does anyone know what the issue with this could be?

Additional info:

Base SDK: iOS 4.3

The code in question:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:adminViewController animated:YES];
```

Xcode 4:

[image]

Xcode 3.2:

[image]

Error:

```
! Expected expression before "adminViewController"
```

Comment: Three questions so I can update my answer. What version of Xcode 4, and what is the underlying SDK supported by Xcode 3, and why do you want to do this?

Comment: Xcode 4.2.  Base SDK (i think you want this one) = "Latest iOS 4.3".   And so I can run it on my jailbroken device for testing without a provisioning profile (i couldnt get xcode 4.2 to build on devices without one).

Comment: Urgh... this question is stupid. Just use a provisioning profile and save yourself the pain of using old versions of Xcode... I'll need to see more code for context as your issue is to do with different compilers and your code not being compatible between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode project compatibility flags in Xcode 4 are quite redundant. The flag sets the underlying project format and doesn't handle support for the versions of the iOS SDK you're programming for and the versions of the Objective C language and runtime.

If you can open the project in Xcode 3 (as it looks like you can) then it's 'compatible' as far as Xcode is concerned. If you're seeing compiler errors then your issue is to do with running your code older/different versions of the iOS SDK / LLVM / GCC.

Comment: Well I've used similar code in older projects that worked fine when I used Xcode 3.2.  Thats why im so confused.